# Expand physical disk in Tiered storage on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

I've tiered storage 10GB SSD and 300GB HDD on Windows 2012 R2 guest at ESXi. I've extended the SSD disk as usual, but at Server manager -> Storage pools I still see the old size of SSD in Physical disk section. Can it be refreshed somehow or is it possible to add new SSD disk to existing storage pool?

Comment: Because I need data to be balanced between SSD and HDD based on their usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to extend disk size, but I was able to add a new virtual drive to the pool.

```
$disk = Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName PhysicalDisk5
Add-PhysicalDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName "TieredPool" -PhysicalDisks $disk
```

This add necessary free storage in the Virtual disk which can be later extended in Storage Pool GUI.